# Change from title to random number

Tags: php

I have this code that should rename images. It takes the title of the site and generates a name but if there is no title it just keeps the old name.

How can i make it so that instead of the title it just randoms the number insteed? so instead of "title.extension" it will be `randomnumber.jpg` ?

```
            $tmp = download_url( $img );

            preg_match('/[^\?]+\.(jpg|JPG|jpe|JPE|jpeg|JPEG|gif|GIF|png|PNG)/', $img, $matches);

            $newfn = str_replace(array("%2B", "%52", "%20", "%5"), "B", basename($matches[0]));

            $oofnm = basename($matches[0]);

            if($newfn != $oofnm) {              

                $newfn2 = str_replace(array(".jpg", ".png", ".gif"), "", $newfn);

                $tmppath = pathinfo( $tmp );                                                        // extract path parts
                $newpth = $tmppath['dirname'] . "/". $newfn2 . "." . $tmppath['extension'];   

                rename($tmp, $newpth);                                                                 // renames temp file on server
                $tmp = $newpth;                 
            }

            $file_array['name'] = $newfn;
            $file_array['tmp_name'] = $tmp;

            // If error storing temporarily, unlink
            if ( is_wp_error( $tmp ) ) {
                @unlink($file_array['tmp_name']);
                $file_array['tmp_name'] = '';
                continue;
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just drop all unnecessary:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($matches[0]);
$file_array['name'] = rand(0,time()/1000) . "." . $path_parts['extension'];
```

I am not sure why you are using `time()/1000` as upper bound for `rand` function. I would rather use `rand` with fixed `min` and `max` args or even use more advanced [`mt_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) function.

But I would recommend you to use [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) function for unique file to generate unique file identifiers:

```
$file_array['name'] = uniqid() . "." . $path_parts['extension'];
```

Comment: Hi

Thanks, i edited my mainpost as that did not solved the problem as you can se in the original post. Even with that change the now the original files name is now kept, can you se why the code wont save it with a random number ?

Comment: Just because you rewrite it immediately in the next code line `$file_array['name'] = uniqid() . "." . $path_parts['extension']; $file_array['name'] = $tmp;`. Be more attentive! :)

Comment: found one more question as i made the change, it still keep the original name even with the change. i think i may be just blind but whatever i do it keep the original name on the file O_o i edited the original post with the current code.

Comment: @Rizzzler I can understand why is your code commented out?

Comment: Hi again Zavg

I was googeling around a bit and found out that the script has a file with the code i linked erlier, but they have forgotten to remove that file as it's not used anymore and the code for the image upload has been placed somewhere else, hence the code not working. Now, i found the correct code above and it's the right one becuase it breaks if i fiddle with with. I added that code to the original post now and even this eludes my head, if i try to insert a "rand" somewhere to make it unique and random it breaks, can you se where it should go?

Comment: The code is very quirky, but from what I see `$newfn` contains new file name.

Comment: TRying to change it but whatever i try only the original filnname remain or the code breaks :/